# Color alternating groups of rows except the last row in table

Tags: tables, color, booktabs

I'm coloring alternating groups (5 rows) in a table. I want to do this for the 40 data rows. I don't want to color the last row in the table that's a quality control checklist.

More or less I want to put a overall row limit on my coloring scheme. Below is compilable code to reproduce my output and I have attached an image of the current output with the last row incorrectly colored.

**Output:**
[image]

**Code:**

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside, notitlepage]{article}% calls document type
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, table, xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table utilities
\usepackage{siunitx}% number and symbol alignment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.7pt}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\groupedRowColors}[5][-1]{% [#1: offset], #2: group size, #3: start line, #4: color 1, #5: color 2
    % copied from xcolor.sty
    \global\rownum=\z@
    \global\@rowcolorstrue
    \@ifxempty{#4}%
        {\def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
        {\def\@oddrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#4}}}}%
    \@ifxempty{#5}%
        {\def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
        {\def\@evenrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#5}}}}%
    % simplified (no check for \if@rowcmd)
    \def\@rowcolors{%
        \if@rowcolors
            \noalign{%
                \relax
                \ifnum\rownum<#3
                    \@norowcolor
                % I have changed this check:
                \else \ifodd \numexpr (\rownum-#1)/#2\relax
                    \@oddrowcolor
                \else
                    \@evenrowcolor
                \fi \fi
            }%
        \fi
    }%
    \CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
    \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=-.35in,%
left=1in,right=1in,top=.25in,bottom=.25in,%
footskip=.15in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt
\heavyrulewidth=2pt

\begin{table}[t!]
\begin{tabular}[l]{|p{.6in}|p{2.46in}|p{1in}|p{1.34in}| }
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Date}\rule{.8in}{.1pt} \hspace{.69in} \textbf{Crew}\rule{2.4in}{.1pt}\hspace{.87in} \textbf{Page}\rule{.2in}{.1pt}  \textbf{of}\rule{.25in}{.1pt}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Species}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Location}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Project}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace*{-2.75\baselineskip}
\begin{centering}
\begin{table}[bh!]
\groupedRowColors{5}{-1}{gray!15}{white}
\begin{tabular}{!{\VRule[2pt]}p{.6in}|p{1.5in}|p{.65in}|p{.65in}|p{2.6in}!{\VRule[2pt]}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Count} & \textbf{Tag Number(s)} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Comments}\\
    \bottomrule
    & & & &\\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\

\toprule
\multicolumn{5}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Scanned}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Entered}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Double Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{centering}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\small\textit{\textbf{*} Max 40 Tests per sheet}\hspace{.5in}\textbf{Notes:}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution: adding a `\rowcolor` to your last row.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,11pt,oneside, notitlepage]{article}% calls document type
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames, table, xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}% table utilities
\usepackage{siunitx}% number and symbol alignment
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\pagenumbering{gobble}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{0.7pt}
\newcommand\VRule[1][\arrayrulewidth]{\vrule width #1}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\groupedRowColors}[5][-1]{% [#1: offset], #2: group size, #3: start line, #4: color 1, #5: color 2
    % copied from xcolor.sty
    \global\rownum=\z@
    \global\@rowcolorstrue
    \@ifxempty{#4}%
        {\def\@oddrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
        {\def\@oddrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#4}}}}%
    \@ifxempty{#5}%
        {\def\@evenrowcolor{\@norowcolor}}%
        {\def\@evenrowcolor{\gdef\CT@row@color{\CT@color{#5}}}}%
    % simplified (no check for \if@rowcmd)
    \def\@rowcolors{%
        \if@rowcolors
            \noalign{%
                \relax
                \ifnum\rownum<#3
                    \@norowcolor
                % I have changed this check:
                \else \ifodd \numexpr (\rownum-#1)/#2\relax
                    \@oddrowcolor
                \else
                    \@evenrowcolor
                \fi \fi
            }%
        \fi
    }%
    \CT@everycr{\@rowc@lors\the\everycr}%
    \ignorespaces
}
\makeatother

\usepackage[letterpaper,bindingoffset=-.35in,%
left=1in,right=.9in,top=.25in,bottom=.25in,%
footskip=.15in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}
\belowrulesep=0pt
\aboverulesep=0pt
\heavyrulewidth=2pt

\begin{table}[t!]
\begin{tabular}[l]{|p{.6in}|p{2.46in}|p{1in}|p{1.34in}| }
\toprule
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Date}\rule{.8in}{.1pt} \hspace{.69in} \textbf{Crew}\rule{2.4in}{.1pt}\hspace{.87in} \textbf{Page}\rule{.2in}{.1pt}  \textbf{of}\rule{.25in}{.1pt}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Species}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Location}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Project}\rule{.95in}{.1pt}}\\
\multicolumn{4}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\vspace*{-2.75\baselineskip}
\begin{centering}
\begin{table}[bh!]
\groupedRowColors{5}{-1}{gray!15}{white}
\begin{tabular}{!{\VRule[2pt]}p{.6in}|p{1.5in}|p{.65in}|p{.65in}|p{2.6in}!{\VRule[2pt]}}
    \toprule
    \textbf{Count} & \textbf{Tag Number(s)} & \textbf{Start} & \textbf{End} & \textbf{Comments}\\
    \bottomrule
    & & & &\\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\
    \hline
    & & & & \\

\toprule
\rowcolor{white} \multicolumn{5}{!{\VRule[2pt]}l!{\VRule[2pt]}}{\textbf{Scanned}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Entered}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}\hfill \textbf{Double Checked}\rule{.6in}{.1pt}}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{centering}
\vspace*{-1\baselineskip}
\small\textit{\textbf{*} Max 40 Tests per sheet}\hspace{.5in}\textbf{Notes:}


\end{document}
```

[image]